# Fetch Tracking Numbers with UPS API

Tags: php, .net, api, ups

The official API link from UPS is: https://www.ups.com/us/en/services/technology-integration/developer-api.page? but I cannot find API to get the list of all Tracking Numbers.

I have a registered UPS developer account. I am trying to find official API of UPS from which I can get the list of all Tracking Numbers associated with my account.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If it isn't in their documentation it probably isn't available. Given the amount of data that could be returned I'm not really surprised that they don't provide a way to get everything with a single call.